# QTP WinComboBox Selection Error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp

I have a "WinComboBox" on a webpage. Then I try to select item in it by index. The code is like :

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WinComboBox("List").Select 5
```

Then sometime the selection goes well, sometimes not when the 3rd or 4th item displays for a while in the wincombobox and changes to the 5th at the last moment. Then the script keeps going on. The problem is, in the situation, even 5th item seems well selected, the web application still thinks that the one stays for a long time is the one selected, so the test goes wrong. I've tried a lot of ways, no successful solution. And the values of the items in the combobox are really not regular charactors, so I cannot verify them.

I wonder if someone could enlight me. Many thank in adance.

Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a `WinComboBox` under `Page` there should either be web based test objects or some kind of ActiveX/Java. Try to load all apropriate addins to the application you're testing and see if you can get a more appropriate test object.

Comment: Hi, Motti, thanks for the answer. Yes, in fact, I think it is loaded in Java cause the WinComboBox is a list of certificats to choose. And the action performed after selecting a certificat in the list is to sign something with the it. Unfortunately, I don't have Java add-in. But QTP can recegonize the WinComboBox. Maybe it was because of this, that the selection is not well performed? Thanks

Comment: @allenzzzxd, all addins (including Java) are part of the QTP installation, you can just rerun the installation and add the Java addin.